# Reutilizar función de módulo en otros módulos de reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formularios

Tengo esta función en el modulo A.js en reactjs, que es para controlar *inputs* de un formulario:

```
test(field, e)
{
    let fields = this.state.fields;
    fields[field] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({fields: fields});
    this.test1(e);
}

test1(e)
{
  alert(e.target.value);
}


render(){
       <div>
          <input onChange={this.test.bind(this, "name")} value={this.state.fields["name"]} type = "text" placeholder = "insert your name" className = "form-input"/>
       <div>
```

}

Funciona solamente en su entorno y quiero separarlo en otro módulo o clase. *GroupModules.js* para poder usarlo en cualquier otro módulo, llamándolo desde su clase respectiva.

Hice esto en *GroupModules.js* para probar:

```
test(field, e)
{
    let fields = {};
    fields[field] = e.target.value ;
    console.log('my test value: ',e.target.value);
    console.log('my test first: ', fields);  
}
```

Comment: No he usado react, y nodejs tiene su propia forma de importar y exportar modulos, alguien que me diga si las sentencias import y export funcionarian de manera natural en este caso??

Comment: No se entiende muy bien qué es lo que quieres hacer. ¿Quieres extraer el método `test` a un fichero externo para poder ser usado en cualquiera de tus componentes?

Comment: @Riven a que te riefieres con manera natural? que si el import y el export funcionan igual tanto en reactjs como en nodejs?, si a lo poco que pude ver

Comment: @Kiko, si, me refiero a eso pero en este caso no funcionan de la misma manera al separarlos, ya que si esta dentro de su propio entorno funciona y obtiene los datos que se escribe y se modifica como tiene que modificarse, pero si lo separo en el input text no se puede escribir(no muestra en pantalla lo que se escribe), y solamente muestra un caracter que se introdujo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ReactJS la *programación esta orientada a componentes*, estos tienen una estructura definida y se presentan como *clases* o *funciones* que retornan un código JSX (`return` en componentes funcionales o desde el método `render()` en componentes de clase).

Puedes sacar funciones (y otras estructuras como objetos, arrays, variables, ...) de los componentes para fines concretos y facilitar su uso en diferentes componentes y partes de la aplicación emplazándolas en ficheros `.js`, `.jsx` o `.tsx` (si estas trabajando con *TypeScript*) en su caso.

Yo suelo crear un directorio `helpers` para alojar ficheros con funciones, junto al directorio `components`. Entonces imaginemos que tenemos el fichero:
`helpers\functions.jsx` con una función de nombre `xxx()` y un componente llamado `Test` en `components\Test.jsx`.

En `helpers\functions.jsx` tengo:

```
export const xxx = () => 
{
    console.log('Has llamado a xxx()');
}
```

Y en el fichero del componente `components\Test.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { xxx } from '../helpers/functions';

function Test()
{
    // Llamo a la función importada de "functions.jsx"
    xxx();

    return (
        <div>
            Componente de prueba
        </div>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: En helpers\functions.jsx, 

la estructura tiene que ir de la siguiente manera?

import React from 'react';
functions extends Components
{
      ...
     export const xx(){...}
     ...
}

o no importaria si se lo declara como en js(sin la herencia Component de react)?

Comment: No es necesario hacer esa `import`, si tu fichero sólo contiene *JS* o *TS*. Solo exportar la función o las funciones que creas. Necesitas importar `React` si por ejemplo vas a añadir algo de *JSX*, pero en ese caso podría ser mejor crear un componente.

Comment: ok muchas gracias, me ayudaste mucho en ese problema, lo intentare, se nota que sabes de reactjs, y aprovechando eso, sabes como puedo hacer un navbar que se permanezca en la misma pagina si por si acaso se le actualiza la pagina en la que se esta, y que me aconsejas para hacer un navbar de acuerdo a un tipo de usuario por elejemplo, y tbn conoces donde hablen de reactjs desde basico a avanzado por asi decirlo.

Comment: o tbn un navbar donde digamos tienes Administrador - Menu - Extras, presionas Administrador por ejemplo, en el menu que aparexca Menu - Extras, y tbn que al actualizarlo se quede ahi mismo, te lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: Plantea lo del navbar en otra pregunta y trata de que no sea algo demasiado amplio o basado en opiniones, se presta a ello. Puedes empezar haciendo un navbar donde aparezca un botón para ir a la página de inicio cuando estas en otras páginas e ir añadiendo elementos. Se pueden mostrar o no cosas en un componente de acuerdo a un condicional. La doc oficial de React tiene bastantes cosas: https://es.reactjs.org/, otro sitio con muchos recursos (en ingles) es https://dev.to/ o https://medium.com/. Me temo que sólo se aprende con el tiempo y haciendo cosas.

Comment: tienes razon, y muchas gracias